# Is there a difference between "predate" and "antedate"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, synonyms

Collins [defines](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/predate) *predate* (third meaning) as

> to be or occur at an earlier date than; precede in time

The same dictionary [defines](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/antedate) *antedate* (first meaning) as

> to be or occur at an earlier date than

While there are other meanings for both words, I'd like to know if there is a difference in their usage, when they're used to mean "occur at an earlier date," or if they can always be used interchangeably in this sense.

Comment: I think they are interchangeable. Predate vs antedate: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predate%2Cantedate%2Cpredates%2Cantedates%2C+predated%2C+antedated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpredate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantedate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpredates%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantedates%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpredated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cantedated%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Predate" is the stiff drink I have before I go on that date with my auntie.

Comment: Antedate predates predate.

Comment: Hope predate has no link to predator :) Antedate, visibly doesn't.  In negotiable instruments, antedate and postdate are used, like antedated cheque/ postdated cheque. (check).  Can we read it with the formation of anterior/ posterior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) provides these definitions for *antedate*:

> **antedate** *vt* (1572) 1 a : to date as of a time prior to that of execution b : to assign to a date prior to that of actual occurrence 2 archaic ANTICIPATE 3 : to precede in time

and this one for *predate*:

> **predate** *vt* (ca. 1864) ANTEDATE

Roughly the same definitions of *antedate* and the explicit equating of *predate* with, simply, "antedate" go back to the Fifth Collegiate (1936). This suggests that, with regard to the senses covered by the longtime definitions of *antedate*, there is no meaningful difference in usage.

Meanwhile, in the 70 years between 1936 and 2005, the relative popularity of the two terms changed considerably, as this Ngram chart for *antedated* (blue line) versus *predated* (red line) illustrates:

[image]

Although the decline in *antedated* seems to mirror the rise in *predated*, a confounding variable is at work: use of *predated* as a past tense of *predate* in the sense of "acted as a predator upon"—a meaning that [Merriam-Webster as yet does not officially acknowledge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predate), but that is not at all rare in recent Google Books matches such as this one, from [*Folia Zoologica*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6dHzAAAAMAAJ&q=%22predated+by+an+avian+predator,+while%22&dq=%22predated+by+an+avian+predator,+while%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Slm8VIG4N463yATIq4GQCw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA), volume 53 (2004) [snippet]:

> In 2002, 34% of the nests were **predated**, while this proportion increased to 76% in 2003 (X'with the Yates correction = 55.9, df = 1, P< 0.001). From the 34 destroyed nests in 2002, only 8.8% (3 nests) was **predated** by an avian predator, while a medium-sized mammal predated in 64.7% of the cases (22 nests). The fox was proved to have **predated** nests three times more frequently than the marten (23.5% versus 8.8%).

Still, predator predating notwithstanding, the frequency of *antedated* has fallen considerably since 1940, and the frequency of *predated* has risen quite a bit, so it appears that the popular preference has shifted in the past 70 years from *antedate* to *predate*.

Two years before Merriam-Webster's first sighting of *predate*, Westland Marston, [*The Family Credit, and Other Tales*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_kBWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22antedated+the+cheque%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wUa8VMP8CYqhyQSehoH4Dw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22antedated%20the%20cheque%22&f=false) (1862) included this instance of *antedated*:

> He [Percy Witham] drew forth the cheque book, and with the help of his pen-knife took out a leaf so skilfully that it was hardly possible to detect the excision. To avoid suspicion he filled up the page for an amount something exceeding his debt, **antedated** the cheque by a day, and made it payable to a feigned name, that of George Lucas.

But today, an author describing the same scene might be at least as likely to use *predated*.